# Do patchelf modify lib's section offset?

Tags: linux, patch, elf, prelink

I'm trying to check the following issue

mylib.so don't have SONAME.

So, I added SONAME by using patchelf like below command

```
patchelf --set-soname "libmylib.so" libmylib.so
```

And i checked elf info by using readelf -a

Next, I used 'prelink' for reducing boot time.

but error occurred with below log

```
root@:~# prelink -aRm
prelink: /usr/lib/libmylib.so: section file offsets not monotonically increasing
```

Maybe... I think that patchelf have effects on mylib's elf info, structure

Do patchelf modify lib section offset?

I wonder how patchelf affects elf info.

+) readelf output compare
left is patchelf not applied output and another is which patchelf applied.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AH5r.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder how patchelf affects elf info.

You don't need to *wonder* -- you could just *see*.

Compare the output from `readelf -WS libmyib.so` before and after, and you will observe that `patchelf` *does* affect ELF info (it would be *pointless* if it didn't).

Comment: I checked readelf output like your comment. section header offset was changed like attached output in origin post.  So, ```prelink: /usr/lib/libmylib.so: section file offsets not monotonically increasing``` was printed....  Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: @rewyear You want two answers for the price of one? Accept this one -- it answered your question. Ask a new one, with your actual question. http://xyproblem.info may be relevant here as well.

Comment: Oh I'm Sorry for my mistake.... I apologize it. I take your advice and will ask question in new post Thanks